# flask started single threaded or not?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

There are a lot of ways to start flask and specify how many threads it will use to serve requests and I would like to have code to check this and emit a warning when it starts with multi-threading enabled (since my `Matlibplot` graphics won't work otherwise). I remember recently coming across someone saying there was a not yet documented variable for this, but I failed to note it and now I can't find it.

Anyone know what it is? Or another way to figure this out? Something that will always work, regardless of what webserver is underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [is_multithread](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=is_multithreading#flask.Request.is_multithread) flag of Request like so:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return {"is_multithread": request.is_multithread}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is what I saw when browsing, but it seems like the right way to do it. Lots of other interesting stuff in that `request` object too. Thanks for the answer. Built it in and it works.